# Error in LSTM nlp multiclass model :- ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 3) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, valueerror

I am working on an email-classifier (using Tensorflow and keras) for whom I created a dataset myself. It has 3 classes - `spam`, `feedback/advice` and `complaint`. It is giving an error: `ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 3) are incompatible` when I fit the model. I read a few answers on it which said that I need to use `to_categorical()` on my training and validation data `(X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val)`. But that also gives a new errors like axis error and more commonly my session on colab crashes. I am totally confused please help:

My code:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GWMx1p9XhQjbC-CD5CQsVpVIn4jvxG6m?usp=sharing

My dataset:
https://www.kaggle.com/ayaanmustafa/email-classification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64223156/yet-another-error-when-checking-target-expected-dense-2-to-have-shape-4-but/64224308#64224308). In short, convert your target variable to one hot. It's shape is `(batch_size, 1)` and it should be `(batch_size, 3)`

Comment: It fixed the crashing and the earlier value error but  now I get this `ValueError: Input 0 of layer bidirectional is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 32, 3, 16]` please help

Comment: Oh I had applied tf.one_hot() to my training data as well. When I removed that it started working.